# Sample size calculation for multi-level models

Tags: r, sample-size

When using the `longpower` package in R for calculating statistical power and, respectiely, sample size:
How do I know which of the functions of the longpower package I should use?
Specifically, I am calculating a Growth Curve Model with time+time^2 and am not sure which of the tests to use for statistical power calculations.

The `longpower` package provides the following Options:

```
diggle.linear.power 
edland.linear.power 
liu.liang.linear.power  
lmmpower-methods 
power.mmrm 
power.mmrm.ar1 
print.power.longtest
```

My model is the following:

```
ModelM5 <- lme(action~time+time^2*se, random=~1+time+time^2|ID, data=school_l_tg, na.action=na.omit, control=list(opt = "optim"))
```

Comment: Is this information not provided in the package's documentation?

Comment: At least I could not find it